# How to assign a specific icon to a specific weapon?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns

Each weapon in the game does have an icon that will be shown on screen when the weapon is picked up.

The weapons are implement as different classes all based on the same base abstract class.

What I'm trying to sketch up is how to define such relationship in the editor, specifically, I want to be able to change a weapon's icon by drag'n'drop a texture on some object in the inspector.

What I'm not looking for:

- the use of enumerations to declare such relationship
- not declaring a direct reference to a texture asset, i.e. a path.

How would you achieve that?

Comment: You can use `[SerializeField] private Sprite icon;`, unless I'm missing something about the problem.

Comment: Yes you are missing something, where would this field be declared? Create weapon assets? How about when two players pick the same weapon, create two assets? I guess you get the point.

Comment: You might need to explain a bit more about how your systems work in your project. Without some code it's hard to know why this wouldn't work. The `Sprite` would be declared in your base class script (let's say Weapon.cs). Then you would make prefabs that use this script (or subclasses of it), and the icon would be saved on the Prefab. Or you could use ScriptableObjects. Either way, you will need to store the data on an asset - unless you're happy to load it by its asset path string.

Comment: There is no weapon system in place, therefore, I have complete freedom in how to implement it. Indeed that relationship would be stored somehow in an asset. You suggested a way but didn't actually answer on where that actual field should be declared; that is the whole point of the question, where should that field be declared, knowing that its value should be modifiable from within the editor.

Comment: Does your weapon base class derive from MonoBehaviour? If so, then declare the Sprite there. If not then use ScriptableObjects, which are effectively "data as assets". Create the ScriptableObject "template" called WeaponData and declare the Sprite here. Then you would create 1 asset for each weapon **from this ScriptableObject**, and put assign icons to those assets in the inspector. Then have your weapons system reference WeaponData and you can drag in the scriptable object which references the icon sprites.

Comment: That second solution seems the right way, it is simple and effective. 

Comment: I strongly advised you not to use enumerations if you want to add your content afterward. Data can always be updated without the need to recompile the app. And any change with your enumeration will require full recompilation.

Comment: Also in the case of the not-too-small project, it can be good to use just keys (even string ones) for any resource and to pass it afterward to some kind of resource manager.

Comment: Anyway, it depends on your needs. Right now, as far as I understood, we are talking about an abstract idea, not a concrete system with concrete requirements.

Comment: Of course, enums are to avoid at all cost. As for the keys, I don't know tbh. It's not that there's nothing in place but that has to be rewritten and thus, can definitely be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to declare a `Sprite` reference in a `MonoBehaviour` or `ScriptableObject` to be assigned in the editor/inspector.

```cs
[SerializeField] private Sprite icon;

public Sprite GetIcon()
{
    return icon;
}
```

---

**MonoBehaviour**

Using `MonoBehaviour` is a common method to store data on objects where the data should be assigned in the editor/inspector. Those objects can be prefabbed to exist as assets. This assumes your weapons exist as game objects.

- Declare the `Sprite` inside a `MonoBehaviour` that is common to all weapons (e.g., a common Weapon.cs, or the base class that you mentioned).
- Then you can create objects (and prefabs of those objects) with the MonoBehaviour attached and assign icons in the inspector.

---

**ScriptableObject**

You can alternatively use a `ScriptableObject`, which can be thought of as "data as assets".

- Create the `ScriptableObject` "template" called WeaponData and declare the `Sprite` inside.
- Create 1 WeaponData asset for each weapon and assign icons to those assets in the inspector.
- Have your game systems reference WeaponData to get the icon Sprite.

[Scriptable Object Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html)

Comment: The key in this is answer is the word 'template', by doing so, it removes lot of upfront trouble.

Comment: @aybe if it is just about templates it sounds like you are better of simply using [prefabs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html) .. I still don't really see the need for ScriptableObject in this use case ... just expose the field in your abstract `MonoBehaviour` base class for those weapons and then create prefabs with different implementations

Comment: @derHugo Right now what I've done is I've added assets for each weapon, they all have their icon assigned from inspector. This will be also the perfect place to set their defaults. Furthermore, the lower level inheritance, SO instead of MB is something great as they're won't be tied to a GO. I fail to understand how your solution would be simpler and/or more effective than this, if you could elaborate on that.

Comment: well at some point in order to "spawn" a visual weapon you either way will need a `MonoBehaviour` for it anyway ... so yes GO is one way to achieve different settings but the same you could achieve by directly have different prefab overloads with different settings and different weapon behaviour implementations derived from a base abstract `Weapon : MonoBehaviour`. We would require a lot more details about your exact environment and use case to tell what would be "best" .. I'm just saying so far I don't really see the need for going through SO